# Naming non-living things

Tags: creative-writing, naming

I know two ways of naming things. One is to use latin prefixes and suffixes and try to have them match the object you are naming with its definition. The other is to use metaphors based on how it looks. What are some other ways? I would like as many answers as possible, one is enough as long as it wasn't mentioned by another user.

Comment: This question is too broad. *Anything*, any random combination of letters, could be the name of an object. You point at a new thing that doesn't have a name yet, you say "this is a sghsiyhslhng", and that's it.

Comment: You're asking for a list, with no clear parameters to decide whether one approach is better than another.  There are *way* more ways to name objects than you've listed -- for one thing, Latin isn't the only language that supplies roots.  Please [edit] to more clearly describe the problem you are trying to solve.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you specify "non-living things". Wouldn't any method also apply to, say, a species on an alien planet, or a new kind of monster, or even a person? Options: Take a word - say, *planet* - and translate it into Icelandic (reikistjarna), Burmese (gyaoh), Igbo (uwa), etc. Write a word backwards. Type random letters. Use archaic words - see for example Poul Anderson's [Uncleftish Beholding](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/cross_fac/complexity/people/students/dtc/students2011/maitland/fun/). :-)

Comment: What types of things are you naming? Who is your audience?  Who in story needs to refer to the things?

Comment: Voting to reopen. The OP gave examples that are clearly NOT random strings of letters – rather implying an evolution or scientific process, and there are 2 answers that are NOT random strings of letters, but both examples of real world scientific nomenclature.

Answer (score 2):

### Name them with a random sequential system in the order they are discovered.

This is how [star classifications](http://www.astronomytrek.com/list-of-different-star-types/) happened. They started with A and B. Then a bunch of letters were wrong and got dropped. Now we know better and have put them in order of temperature, but we still have the category names in the wrong order: O, B, A, F, G, K, and M.

Answer (score 2):

### Name them after the person who discovered them.

Many areas and companies are named in this way.